# Embed HTML in PHP Code

Tags: php, html, json, web

I have to fetch data using a REST Api, and my response is in json. After decoding the response is in an array I have to display it in a webpage such that each of the responses in the array get displayed in a specific display format (Just Like tweets in twitter are displayed in a specific box type format).How to loop through the array in php and display it ? The only solution I find is embedding the HTML in php using echo which I did but it is not working .And the debugger isn't helping much. 
What am I missing ?

Please advise what to do.

Here is my code:

```
    echo  "<div class="tweet original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-  popup-actionable js-original-tweet my-tweet" data-tweet-id="515380319977893890"data-item-id="515380319977893890"  data-name="" data-user-id="2665607941" data-expanded-footer="&lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer&quot;&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;entities-media-container js-media-container&quot; style=&quot;min-height:0px&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;js-machine-translated-tweet-container&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container &quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;client-and-actions&quot;&gt;&#10;  &lt;span class=&quot;metadata&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;span&gt;11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014&lt;/span&gt;&#10;&#10;       &amp;middot; &lt;a class=&quot;permalink-link js-permalink js-nav&quot; href=&quot;/status/515380319977893890&quot;  tabindex=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;Details&lt;/a&gt;&#10;    &#10;&#10;&#10;  &lt;/span&gt;&#10;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;" data-you-follow="false"data-you-block="false">" ;

    echo "<div class="content">" ;

    echo "<div class="stream-item-header">" ;

    echo "<a  class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav" data-user-id="2665607941">
           <img class="avatar js-action-profile-avatar" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/506790785572814848/vdj_UAuZ_bigger.jpeg" alt="">
           <strong class="fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id" data-aria-label-part> </strong>
           <span>&rlm;</span><span class="username js-action-profile-name" data-aria-label-part><s></s><b>   </b></span>
           </a>" ;

    echo "<small class="time">
          <a  class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" title="11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014" ><span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " 
           data-aria-label-part="last" data-time="1411711218" data-time-ms="1411711218000" data-long-form="true">Sep 25</span></a>
          </small>" ;


    echo"</div>";

    echo "<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0"> </p>" ;

    echo "<div class="stream-item-footer">";

    echo "<ul class="tweet-actions js-actions">";

    echo "<li class="more-tweet-actions">";
    echo "<div class="action-more-container">";
    echo "<div class="dropdown">";
    echo "<button type="button" class="btn-link with-icn dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle js-tooltip">";
    echo "<span class="Icon Icon--delete"></span>";
    echo "<b>Delete</b>";
    echo "</button>";
    echo "<div class="dropdown-menu">";
   echo "<div class="dropdown-caret">";
echo "<div class="caret-outer"></div>";
echo "<div class="caret-inner"></div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>"; 
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

---

After Scott's answer I changed my code , but still it is not working and I am not getting it.

```
 echo  "<div class=\"tweet original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable js-original-tweet
```

my-tweet\" data-tweet-id="515380319977893890\"data-item-id=\"515380319977893890\"  data-name=\"\" data-user-id=\"2665607941\"
data-expanded-footer=\"<div class="js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer">



    <div class="entities-media-container js-media-container" style="min-height:0px">
    </div>

  <div class="js-machine-translated-tweet-container"></div>
    <div class="js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container ">
    </div>

  <div class="client-and-actions">
  <span class="metadata">
    <span>11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014</span>

       &middot; <a class="permalink-link js-permalink js-nav" href="/status/515380319977893890"  tabindex="-1">Details</a>
    


  </span>
</div>


</div>
"
data-you-follow=\"false\"data-you-block=\"false\">" ;

echo   "" ;

```
  echo   "<div class=\"stream-item-header\">" ;

     echo "<a  class=\"account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav\" data-user-id=\"2665607941\
     ">
           <img class=\"avatar js-action-profile-avatar\" src=\"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/506790785572814848/vdj_UAuZ_bigger.jpeg\" alt=\"\">
           <strong class=\"fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id\" data-aria-label-part> </strong>
           <span>&rlm;</span><span class=\"username js-action-profile-name\" data-aria-label-part><s></s><b>   </b></span>
           </a>" ;

    echo "<small class=\"time\">
          <a  class=\"tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip\" title=\"11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014\" ><span class=\"_timestamp js-short-timestamp \" 
           data-aria-label-part=\"last\" data-time=\"1411711218\" data-time-ms=\"1411711218000\" data-long-form=\"true\">Sep 25</span></a>
          </small>" ;


    echo"</div>";

    echo "<p class=\"js-tweet-text tweet-text\" lang=\"en\" data-aria-label-part=\"0\"> </p>" ;

    echo "<div class=\"stream-item-footer\">";

    echo "<ul class=\"tweet-actions js-actions">";

    echo "<li class=\"more-tweet-actions\">";
    echo "<div class=\"action-more-container\">";
    echo "<div class=\"dropdown\">";
    echo "<button type=\"button" class=\"btn-link with-icn dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle js-tooltip\">";
    echo "<span class=\"Icon Icon--delete\"></span>";
    echo "<b>Delete</b>";
    echo "</button>";
    echo "<div class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
   echo "<div class=\"dropdown-caret\">";
echo "<div class=\"caret-outer\"></div>";
echo "<div class=\"caret-inner\"></div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>"; 
echo   "</div>";
echo   "</div>";
```

Comment: Escape the quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your single and double quotes.  The strings are being returned are being truncated.  This is invalid:

```
 echo   "<div class="stream-item-header">" ;
```

Change it to:

```
echo   "<div class=\"stream-item-header\">" ;
```

Or:

```
echo   "<div class='stream-item-header'>" ;
```

**And repeat this fix for each of your echo lines.**

For example, this:

```
echo  "<div class="tweet original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-  popup-actionable js-original-tweet my-tweet" data-tweet-id="515380319977893890"data-item-id="515380319977893890"  data-name="" data-user-id="2665607941" data-expanded-footer="&lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer&quot;&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;entities-media-container js-media-container&quot; style=&quot;min-height:0px&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;js-machine-translated-tweet-container&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container &quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;client-and-actions&quot;&gt;&#10;  &lt;span class=&quot;metadata&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;span&gt;11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014&lt;/span&gt;&#10;&#10;       &amp;middot; &lt;a class=&quot;permalink-link js-permalink js-nav&quot; href=&quot;/status/515380319977893890&quot;  tabindex=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;Details&lt;/a&gt;&#10;    &#10;&#10;&#10;  &lt;/span&gt;&#10;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;" data-you-follow="false"data-you-block="false">" ;
```

Becomes this:

```
echo  "<div class=\"tweet original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-  popup-actionable js-original-tweet my-tweet\" data-tweet-id=\"515380319977893890\" data-item-id=\"515380319977893890\"  data-name=\"\" data-user-id=\"2665607941\" data-expanded-footer=\"&lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer&quot;&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;entities-media-container js-media-container&quot; style=&quot;min-height:0px&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;js-machine-translated-tweet-container&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container &quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;client-and-actions&quot;&gt;&#10;  &lt;span class=&quot;metadata&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;span&gt;11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014&lt;/span&gt;&#10;&#10;       &amp;middot; &lt;a class=&quot;permalink-link js-permalink js-nav&quot; href=&quot;/status/515380319977893890&quot;  tabindex=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;Details&lt;/a&gt;&#10;    &#10;&#10;&#10;  &lt;/span&gt;&#10;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&lt;/div&gt;&#10;\" data-you-follow=\"false\" data-you-block=\"false\">" ;
```

For a more advanced trick, you can move your entire HTML to a separate file, an HTML template if you will.  Then read in the file contents via PHP and find/replace the variables or dynamic parts as you need.  This may be beyond the scope of your question however.

Comment: I changed the entire code but still nothing is being displayed, could there be any other error ?

Comment: Yes, check all of your double quotes.

Comment: If the second method could work in my case, could you please tell me a bit about it or give any links to learn it. I need to fix my stuff today only. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, if you have a " inside of two other " then you need to change it to \" so that it doesn't prematurely end the string.

Comment: or simply use the [addslashes](http://it2.php.net/manual/it/function.addslashes.php)
function for auto-esacpe both single and double quote in the string before echo

Comment: @Scott I have posted the changed code above.I have made all the changes I guess.

Comment: You are still missing a few slashes.  See how StackOverflow is coloring the code?  That shows you where you are missing the escape slash.  Please upvote my comments or answers if my time/assistance is helping you.

Comment: @Andrea_86 Could you check a bit what is wrong with the updated code. I have put slashes but still noting gets displayed. Not even a echo like echo "Ok" ;  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the quotes inside the echo need to be escaped:

```
echo "<div class=\"stream-item-footer\">";
```

Comment: I changed it but yet nothing is being displayed.

Comment: in all of your echos?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes with \

```
   echo   "<div class=\"content\">" ;
```

Comment: Changes are not working, anything else could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
    echo '<div class="content">';
  echo '<div class="stream-item-header">';
       echo '<a  class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav" data-user-id="2665607941">
           <img class="avatar js-action-profile-avatar" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/506790785572814848/vdj_UAuZ_bigger.jpeg" alt="">
           <strong class="fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id" data-aria-label-part> </strong>
           <span>&rlm;</span><span class="username js-action-profile-name" data-aria-label-part><s></s><b>   </b></span>
           </a>';
    echo '<small class="time">
          <a  class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" title="11:00 PM - 25 Sep 2014" ><span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " 
           data-aria-label-part="last" data-time="1411711218" data-time-ms="1411711218000" data-long-form="true">Sep 25</span></a>
          </small>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0"> </p>';
    echo '<div class="stream-item-footer">';
    echo '<ul class="tweet-actions js-actions">';
    echo '<li class="more-tweet-actions">';
    echo '<div class="action-more-container">';
    echo '<div class="dropdown">';
    echo '<button type="button" class="btn-link with-icn dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle js-tooltip">';
    echo '<span class="Icon Icon--delete"></span>';
    echo '<b>Delete</b>';
    echo '</button>';
    echo '<div class="dropdown-menu">';
   echo '<div class="dropdown-caret">';
echo '<div class="caret-outer"></div>';
echo '<div class="caret-inner"></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>'; 
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: If you're using single quotes when ecoing you don't need to escape the double quotes if you're using double quotes in the HTML, and vice versa. These all work:
` echo   "<div class=\"content\">" ;
 echo   '<div class="content">' ;` 
Just make it a habit to use the opposite depending on what you're using inside. And if you need to you can always escape with \

Comment: Hey I really appreciate your help. I will surely upvote when  I get more reputation

Answer (score 1):

I'l write here my response dude, and hope i'm helping you. But there's nothing new, as Scott say, you missed a lot of double quote and IMHO you're a crazy boy doing it manually (in good sense).

Take you're JSON array and use the function i've linked in the comment in a way like this(hoping you have a similar situation, in other case is the same but you have to complex the code, maybe):

```
....
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($jsonarray); $i++){
echo addslashes($jsonarray[$i]);
}
....
```

In this way all of your code it's escaped, and if the error persist it means that's the problem is elsewhere